# Add docker host into docker network

Tags: docker, docker-network

Step1: create a docker network

```
docker network create my-work-network
```

Step2: add some container into this network

```
docker run ... --name my-work-pg --network my-work-network image1
docker run ... --name my-work-redis --network my-work-network image2
```

My question is:

Current, in `my-work-pg`, I could ping `my-work-redis`, and vice versa.
But, in my docker host, I have to parse two container IP address and 
access those container, is there exist a solution to make my docker host can `JOIN IN` this virtual network?

### purpose

Just for development conveniency, I want to access all started container
in this network directly as if docker host is a container. e.g. I can access postgresql database with following config

```
host: my-work-pg     # pg container host name
port: 5432
```

But, this not exactly what I want.

Comment: Just map the container ports to your docker host: `docker run -p <host_port>:<container_port>`. Afterwards you can access the services using `localhost:port`.

Comment: @zw963: just to understand your purpose, when you said " I want to access all started container in this network directly as if docker host is a container", by default docker containers are accessible from host machine. What else you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose the best way is used link option --link and pass docker_image:name_to_binding, for example to link redis with pg with your configuration it something like that

```
docker run ... --name my-work-redis --link my-work-pg image2
```

In these case the same name of container of pg it used as internal name in redis container, and not need something like my-work-pg:name-pg-internal-redis

Comment: What I want is ping docker client from host, is there a link to support this? and more, docker team seem not favorite --link anymore, and will drop it in future version

Comment: Yes, you' re right, I open the [documentation of docker about legacy links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#updating-the-etchosts-file) and see the red letters announcing that remove that feature. I suggested that use a fixed IP addres in each container using ip or ip6 options, the bridge network created by docker allow to see that IPs

Answer (score 0):

I could assure you there is no such a way to add `docker daemon host` into user-defined network `my-work-network`.
Just like you wrote above, your purpose is for development convenience. So I don't think your configuration `host: my-work-pg` is essential. As @Sebastian mentioned, you could do the mapping of application's port in container and port on host with `-p` flag. Then you may access postgres service through `localhost:5432`.
I suggest you read docs on `[docker.com][1]`.
Hope it helps~